# If $A$ and $B$ are sets, what is commonly denoted by $A+B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

> If $A$ and $B$ are sets, what is commonly defined by $A+B$ ?

I saw it in a exercise list from my classes, and I don't know from where it came.

Comment: Convention is either: $$A+B = A \cup B$$ Or: $$A+B = \{a+b:a \in A \land b \in B\}$$

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: For general sets it doesn't commonly mean anything, but for two sets for which addition of its elements makes sense, it is common to let $A+B=\{a+b~:~a\in A,~b\in B\}$.  In particular the direct sum of two vector spaces.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in my lists $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, so it should be the direct sum. Thank you guys.

Comment: The usage $A + B$ for $A \cup B$ is found in many older books of real analysis (typically before 1960 or so).